# 12.04 wifi problem

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

i know this has been asked a million times and that there are loads of topics on this all over the internet, but no solution worked for me so far.
i have a lenovo computer with a broadcom wifi thingie. i recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on it, and i can't turn wifi on. i logged into the internet using an ethernet connection and downloaded updated and installed all the right drivers using the synaptic package manager, and it didnt help. i tried to clear caches, didnt do anything. i tried to delete the old kernel and reboot- no good. i used alot of those sudo apg-get bc43 commands aswell, they all seem to do something, but i dont get any result. before, they used tto say that they didnt find the package. after i installed it from the synaptic package manager, they all say that the newest version is already installed. anyone has any idea what should i do next?

edit: i did this: sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
now i have the option "enable wireless" under the enable networking option in the internet manu. but it still won't recognize any wifi near me.  my internet switch on my laptop is on btw, and it's working perfectly on windows.

Comment: Did you make sure your wifi is enabled in bios?

Comment: enable bios **wifi** and install **network-manager** along.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the bug not fixed? Its been an year since the 12.04 was launched. I have just shifted from Windows and regretting that. There is a back up though called Wicd but you have to remove the entire buggy network module. Use the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```